# Converting factors in R that are salaries to numeric values

Tags: r

I have a column of salaries in R. They are salaries with 2 decimal points. When I read them in as a CSV, R recognizes the column as Factors. I can't perform functions such as `sum` or `subset` to analyze the data. Thus, I changed the column to numeric with the command:

```
payroll$Total.Earnings <- as.numeric(payroll$Total.Earnings)
```

However, this drastically changes the amounts of the salaries. For example, a person who made `$100381.19` is changed to `86` after I write the command above. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Use `payroll$Total.Earnings <- as.numeric(as.character(payroll$Total.Earnings))` instead

Comment: when I do  payroll$Total.Earnings <- as.numeric(as.character(payroll$Total.Earnings)) I get NAs. The warning message says "NAs introduced by coercion "

Comment: Do you have the dollar `$` sign in your salary values? If that is the case, you have to remove it, because R doesn't know that `$` means dollar (it's just a character like any other). So, if that is the case, you need to get rid of the dollar sign, before converting it to numeric. You can, for example, use the `sub()` function like so: `as.numeric(sub("\\$", "", as.character(payroll$Total.Earnings)))`.